# Dynamically resizing div w/ javascript and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to resize a div with a button click, using javascript and jquery. This is all in an asp.net web form. I have little experience with javascript and practically none with jquery. This is the code I have so far with help from other SO members. Besides it not working, I know there's something wrong because the alerts are not being displayed.

Any help is appreciated.

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Data Display</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function toggleGridContent() {
            var id = "#gridViewContainer";
            if ($(id).hasClass("small")) {
                alert("found");
                $(id).attr("class", "large");
            } else {
                alert("not");
                $(id).attr("class", "small");
            }
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .small {
            height: 200px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .large {
            height: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <input type="button" onclick="toggleGridContent()" value="toggleGridContent" />

    <div class="small" id="gridViewContainer" style="border: 1px solid red">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridViewNsbAll" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="subgroup" HeaderText="subgroup"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="count" HeaderText="count"></asp:BoundField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a reference to the jQuery library. If you have it in your web site you can use something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Easier would be to link to the latest hosted version

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thanks very much.